# Migrate from Outlook Contacts (Address Book) to something with rich text in Notes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, contacts, address-book

In the Contacts (Address Book) part of Outlook for Mac 2011, I use rich text formatting (including links) for Notes.

I'd like to migrate away from Microsoft to something that is open source. From what I can tell, Thunderbird does not support rich text formatting in the Notes tab. Is this correct?

Which program can I migrate to, that supports rich text formatting in the Notes section of Contacts (or Address Book)?

Comment: Can you recommend a site that is more appropriate?  StackOverflow?